# Input seems disabled for some reason, only with Firefox

Tags: firefox, input

I got this problem with Firefox and input elements.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nanny07/dmW9p/)

In this menu, if you navigate to "Strumenti" -> "Colonne" -> "Prova6", you will see a `table` inside a `li` with two inputs and one combobox.
The inputs seems to be disabled but only with Firefox: with Chrome or IE it's all working as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a deep search, I finally found the problem:

```
$( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

This line, included in [this jqueryUI demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/), disable the input in FF.

[JsFiddle of the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/nanny07/dmW9p/39/)

There is also this css `-moz-user-select: none;` that I personally wrote for disable selection over the text of my menu that cause a wired behavior, alwasys in FF: I will delete it for my solution.